# Saving variables to localstorage with Phonegap

Tags: html, cordova, local-storage

I have a cookie clicker like app, and I'm up to the stage where I need to save the amount of cookies a user has locally. But because this is an ever changing variable, I'm having trouble doing it.

```
var cookies = 0;
```

How would I implement localstorage of this, because every time  the var changes I end up with 0001 and similar results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova use regular webview so you can use localstorage like in a webkit browser.

Save value:

`localStorage.setItem("cookies ", 1);`

Read Value:

```
var cookies =localStorage.getItem("cookies");
```

Comment: Hi, While this is what I used, I made more developments, since the time I asked the question. Now I'm wondering how I would get the value of the localstorage, and update var cookies, without actually setting var cookies to the localstorage. Does this make sense?

Comment: Hi, i don't understand question very well, but my suggestion is to create a wrapper object for manage cookies variable that persist value in loacl storage.